# How to _GET multiple value checkbox WP_Query in Custom Toxonomy / Custom Fields

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, meta-query

I try to make a sort of fiter for my website. Goal is for the visitors to query results by prices ('prix') and hobbies ('aimerparlapersonne').

Prices are numbers between min and max. Hobbies is checkbox. I want to allow my visitors to check 2 boxes or more. I made a custom toxonomy of post section.

**My problem**
Query doesn't work well with 2 boxes checked. That's work only with one... My URL result is
?minprice=&maxprice=&aimerparlapersonne=decoration&aimerparlapersonne=sport

Can you help me please ?

This is my form with prices and hobbies

```
 <form action=" <?php $term_link; ?>" method="get">
         <label>min:</label>
         <input type="number" name="minprice" value="<?php echo $minprice; ?>">
         <label>max:</label>
         <input type="number" name="maxprice" value="<?php echo $maxprice; ?>">


         <label>Hobbies:</label>
         <div>
      <p><input type="checkbox" id="aimerparlapersonne" name="aimerparlapersonne" value="decoration">Décoration</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" id="aimerparlapersonne" name="aimerparlapersonne" value="sport">Sport</p>

</div>


         <button type="submit" name="">Filter</button>
 </form>
```

I use GET method after that.

```
        <?php
                 if($_GET['minprice'] && !empty($_GET['minprice']))
                 {
                     $minprice = $_GET['minprice'];
                 } else {
                     $minprice = 0;
                 }

                 if($_GET['maxprice'] && !empty($_GET['maxprice']))
                 {
                     $maxprice = $_GET['maxprice'];
                 } else {
                     $maxprice = 999999;
                 }


                    if($_GET['aimerparlapersonne'] && !empty($_GET['aimerparlapersonne']))
                    {
                        $aimerparlapersonne = $_GET['aimerparlapersonne'];



                    }

                         ?>
```

And for finish my WP_Query

```
<?php
                $qobjet = get_queried_object();
$args = array(
                                     'post_type' => 'post',
                                     'posts_per_page' => 20 ,
                                     'meta_query' => array(
                                             array(
                                                     'key' => 'prix',
                                                     'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                                                     'value' => array($minprice, $maxprice),
                                                     'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                                             ),
                                             array(
                                                    'key' => 'aimerparlapersonne',
                                                    'value' => $aimerparlapersonne,
                                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                            ),

                                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                                'tax_query' => array(

                     array(
                                 'taxonomy' => $qobjet->taxonomy,
                                 'field' => 'id',
                                 'terms' => $qobjet->term_id,
                     ),

                 ),
             ),      );


                             $query = new WP_Query($args);

             ?>

                <?php if ($query->have_posts() ) : while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query-> the_post(); // run the loop ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content-category', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif;?>
    <?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

**EDIT**

I add this code Now that’s work but it’s too restrictiv. I have 3 checkbox with value “decoration”, “sport”, “jeux”. When I checked one it’s that’s return the right post. When I check 2 or more this return only post the values I want all the post with only 1 value correct not specially too.

Exemple
Post 1 = decoration, sport
Post 2 = decoration, jeux
Post 3 = jeux

If I checked decoration
Return Post 1 and 2 ok

If I checked decoration and jeux
Return Post 2 but I want numbers 2 and 3. I think it’s maybe a compare problem ?

```
$meta_query = array('passion' => 'OR');
    foreach((array) $passion as $passions){
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'aimerparlapersonne',
        'value'   => $passions,
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    );
}
                    }
$qobjet = get_queried_object();
$args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'post',
                                    'posts_per_page' => 20  ,
                                    'tax_query' => array(
                                            array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => $qobjet->taxonomy,
                                                        'field' => 'id',
                                                        'terms' => $qobjet->term_id,
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                                    'meta_query' => array(
                                            array(
                                                    'key' => 'prix',
                                                    'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                                                    'value' => array($minprice, $maxprice),
                                                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                                            ),

                                            'meta_query' => $meta_query,
                                     ),
                                 );


                             $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

---

Thanks for your replies solution is here https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/wp_query-checkbox-array-string-error/

Comment: now with your edit, you have a second question, please close this one, and make that second question in a new one. for those who have the same doubt you had can see the answer.

Comment: I moved your answer to an edit as it was just a link somewhere else, you need to write an answer that isn't just a link offsite, it needs to contain the solution

Answer (score 0):

your checkboxes have the same id, the id is unique, otherwise would be a class.
in the forms the checkboxes should use each one an unique id and name,check this example at [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_checkbox)
then when checking for the $_GET we should use the isset because if for some reason does not have that $_GET will return an error in the code.

```php
if(isset($_GET['minprice']) && !empty($_GET['minprice']))
  {
     $minprice = $_GET['minprice'];
  } else {
     $minprice = 0;
  }
```

and the !empty($_GET['minprice']) should be set in the html instead as requiered like so

```php
<label>min:</label>
<input type="number" name="minprice" value="<?php echo $minprice; ?>" required >
```

all this should putt your code working, I even had check nothing more because this should respond to your question, if some issue more appear give feedback.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @tiago-calado I edited my code ;)

Comment: all the code after the edit title seems normal, Only with more info I could say something, this said, only with the results of that code and with the desired results wanted.